# Adjust color object saturation

Tags: color

I'm trying to adjust the saturation of a color object but it there does not seem to be an easy way of accomplishing this without evaluating colorconvert to HSL and tweaking this. but I need to adjust this inline inside a function over a list so doing it manually like this is quite tedious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to adjust the saturation of each image individually then there is really no way to automate it. To apply the same saturation you can do something like this, but it is quite slow.

```
saturation = 2;
ExampleData[{"TestImage", #}] & /@ {"Apples", "Flower", "House"} //
  ColorConvert[#, "HSB"] & //
  Map[ImageApply[({#[[1]], saturation #[[2]], #[[3]]} &), #] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

to be compared to

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can use `ImageMultiply` instead of `ImageApply` to multiply the second channel with a value. I like to use `"LCH"` instead of `"HSB"` for this type of adjustment. You need to modify the C channel. It's a more flexible way to adjust saturation. Note that converting to LCH will turn the image into a floating point type from a byte type and that C can (and should) go above 1.0.

Comment: Thank you this is actually even better for my needs!

Comment: @Szabolcs would you mind providing an example of your version?

Comment: @skyfire `With[
 {asc = <|"LCH" -> ColorConvert[img, "LCH"], "HSB" -> ColorConvert[img, "HSB"]|>},
 Manipulate[
  ImageMultiply[asc[type], {1, c, 1}],
  {{c, 1}, 0, 2}, {type, {"LCH", "HSB"}}
 ]
]` Make sure `img` is rescaled to 500 pixels or smaller for decent performance. There's not enough new here to warrant an answer. Since C in LCH is unbounded, this will quickly start clipping colours, be careful! S in HSB will saturate at 1 and then you can't increase saturation anymore.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you!